# page view count without file or DB in php and html

Tags: php, html, view, count

Hi
Is it possible to show page view count without using file or database to store it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store it somewhere... where were you expecting to store it other than the filesystem or a database? Options like APC and memcache do exist, but these aren't 100% persistent in the same way as file or db. And as most hosting services give you db access these days, why not use it? Another alternative might be to hook up google analytics.

Comment: Not really - you'll have to store the number *somewhere*. Unless you can tap into an external log file like Apache's, but by default, you can't do that from within PHP

Answer (score 2):

If you're using APC (or some other opcode cache) you can store it in memory. APC Increment would be helpful http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-inc.php, there's similar features for memcached or other services.

Beyond that, it needs to go somewhere, on disk (in a file or a DB), or in memory. There's no built in persistant store with PHP itself (though many opcode caches provide it).